# Perl newline character not enforced within single quoted string (or line read from file)

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script to read a file line by line and some of the lines contain newline (\n) character in it but it is not enforced.

Here is the example I tried and not working for me

```
    my $var1 = 'Hello \n world';
    my $var2 = "$var1";
    my $var3 = '$var1';

    print "    $var2 \n" ;
    print $var3;
```

out put is

```
       Hello \n world
       $var1
```

but I want like below

```
        Hello
        world
```

When I read a line from the file, the line has the newline character in it and that newline character needs to be enforced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes `''` do not interpolate variables or control characters.

This is just the way Perl works.

If you `print '\n'` that will print a literal backslash `\` and a literal n `n`. If you assign this to a variable, it will also assign a literal backslash and a literal n.

Interpolating the variable into another string like `"$foo"` will only interpolate `$foo`, but it will still contain a literal backslash and a literal n.

If wanted to interpolate that as well, you would have to use string `eval`.

```
my $foo = 'Hello\nWorld';
print eval "qq{$foo}";
```

The double quotes `""` are for interpolating `$foo` to the value `Hello\nWorld`, so the literal text will be seen by `eval`, and the `qq{}` double quotes are for wrapping that string into an interpolation double quote so that `eval` will treat it as such and interpolate.

But please don't do that. In most cases you **do not want to use string `eval`**.

---

Since you are talking about reading from a file, this is different. If you read a string from a file and it contains the literal `\` and the literal `n`, then that is **not a newline character**. The `\n` escape sequence is just a visual representation used to create the newline character, which is [`0x0A` in ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/). So your file contains nothing special. Just two characters.

You could replace literal `\` and `n` with a `\n` while processing the file.

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/\\n/\n/g; # \\ creates literal backslash, second half is interpolated
}
```

Comment: *"The double quotes `""` are for changing `$foo` to the value `Hello\nWorld`"*. It may be me, but I took the longest time to understand what you were getting at here. I'm not sure you should be mentioning `eval` at all, and the bolded warning should be *before* the example. But that's not what the double quotes do: they *interpolate* `$foo` to create the string `qq{Hello\nWorld}`. It may also be worth mentioning [`String::Interpolate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Interpolate).

Comment: @Borodin better?

Comment: Hmm. I feel I'm being picky, but I think something along the lines of *so that it is the same as `eval "qq{Hello\nWorld}"`* is more appropriate. `eval` with nested double quotes, especially with mixed delimiters, can be especially difficult to get one's head around.

Comment: Please go ahead and improve the post @Borodin. :)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think it's `print` that's converting `\n` into a newline, but it's not. As you've find out, if you read `Hello \n world␊` from a file and pass it to `print`, it will print `Hello \n world␊`.

It's the double-quoted string literals themselves that produces the transformed strings. For exmple,

- The string literal `'Hello \n world'` produces the 14-character string `Hello \n world`.
- The string literal `"Hello \n world"` produces the 13-character string `Hello ␊ world`.

If you want some kind of conversion to be performed on your input, you will need to tell Perl to perform it.

```
my $s = 'Hello \n world'."\n";
$s =~ s/\\n/\n/g;
print($s);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to replace the literal sequence `\n` with a newline and spaces in your example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $var1 = 'Hello \n world';
my $var2 = "$var1";
my $var3 = '$var1';

my $s = "    $var1 \n";
$s =~ s/\\n/\n   /;
print $s
```

Output:

```
    Hello
    world
```

However, use `s/\\n/\n/` on your file if the whitespace was an unintentional artifact of your example output. This situation is a good illustration of [string interpolation](https://perlmaven.com/quoted-interpolated-and-escaped-strings-in-perl) and `\n` in a Perl string is `\\n`, or an escaped newline.